# Google Pie Charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html

Is possible add simply counter to legends?
In this example:

```
Mushrooms (3)
 Onions (1)
Olives (1)
Zucchini (1)
Pepperoni (2)
```

Is possible to make? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily by including the counter at the end of the legend string. Let's suppose your values come from an object with a structure such as:

```
var data = {
    'Mushrooms': 3,
    'Onions': 1,
    'Olives': 1,
    'Zucchini': 1,
    'Pepperoni': 2
}
```

What you can do is generate a rows array like:

```
var rows = [];
for (ingredient in data) {
    rows.push([
        ingredient + " (" + data[ingredient] + ")",
        data[ingredient
    ])
}
```

You can see it in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/invernizzie/T4yWz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The above is just a demo, when you pass your own objects you can pass any data you like.

Pass in the object(json for example)

```
function drawChart(json_obj){


var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night, Total: ' + json_obj.count,
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};


}

}
```